# ios Json Truncated

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

In one of my project I have used google place api and get the address when tap on map, from google some time came address with special charter like 'Č' and other so that while parsing into `JSON` data is truncated,before send the string with data I am converting it to `UTF8`

`NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [requestString UTF8String] length: [requestString length]];
    [request setHTTPBody:requestData];`

Is there any other way to converting data rather then `UTF8`?

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253417/send-post-request-with-special-characters-ios

Comment: Convert string to jsonstring and pass it to the 'length' parameter of method 'dataWithBytes' and for details follow this link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496292/special-characters-while-parsing-json-in-ios